# How to convert List dict to dict from python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like below...

```
[{u'taxOnTaxInd': True, u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'VAT', u'taxOnTax': {u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'St on VAT', u'taxFacter': 5}, u'taxFacter': 10.0}, {u'taxOnTaxInd': True,u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'GST', u'taxOnTax': {u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'GST', u'taxFacter': 5}, u'taxFacter': 20.0}]
```

I need to convert above list to dictionary to dictionary format like below.

```
{u'taxOnTaxInd': True, u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'VAT', u'taxOnTax': {u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'St on VAT', u'taxFacter': 5}, u'taxFacter': 10.0}, {u'taxOnTaxInd': True,u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'GST', u'taxOnTax': {u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'GST', u'taxFacter': 5}, u'taxFacter': 20.0}
```

How to get this from python.

Comment: You seem to be just accessing the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list with 2 elements which are 2 dictionaries.

```
# Your list
your_list = [{u'taxOnTaxInd': True, u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'VAT', u'taxOnTax': {u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'St on VAT', u'taxFacter': 5}, u'taxFacter': 10.0}, {u'taxOnTaxInd': True,u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'GST', u'taxOnTax': {u'calTypePrcnt': True, u'name': u'GST', u'taxFacter': 5}, u'taxFacter': 20.0}]
```

In python list is a collection of elements. In these case it is a collection of 2 dictionaries. You can extract these 2 dictionaries and keep them separate like this:

```
dict_1 = your_list[0]
dict_2 = your_list[1]

# Do whatever you want with them
```

Or you can convert list to dictionary:

```
your_dict = {x: your_list[x] for x in range(len(your_list))}
```

Where `x` will be key and equal to 0, 1 etc and value is a dictionary element from `your_list`.

Comment: there are two dicts in the above list

Comment: I think list has 2 elements and what op wants is just `[` and `]` removed

Comment: please can you give the answer.

Comment: @RameshBabuMolakalapalli, what you want isn't a dictionary. A tuple maybe, but definitely not dictionary